# SoX command is suddenly not working

Tags: sox

I have this typed into the .bat file:

sox in.wav out.wav trim 0.0065 reverse silence 1 0 0% trim 0.0065 reverse pad 0.0065 0.2

pause

It worked earlier but now the output file is at 0kb. I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Using openSUSE Linux I used your sox command on an arbitrary .wav file and it functioned without error, giving an output file slightly longer than the original but sounding identical. So the expression itself is a valid sox command.

You don't explain the presence of the "pause" command; I am assuming that it is not intended to be part of the sox command since it is not a valid option.

It's possible your system is opening/creating the output file to receive output but when you actually try to read it it has not yet been flushed from cache to permanent storage?